# wp_nav_menu() doesn't work poperly

Tags: wordpress

I need to use custom items_wrap format but it seems like it doesn't work at all.

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( array(
    'menu_class'     =>     'menu',
    'menu'           =>     'mobile-menu',
    'theme_location' =>     'main-navigation',
    'container'       => false,
    'items_wrap'      => '<ul data-role="listview">%3$s</ul>'  ) ); ?>
```

The OUTPUT

```
<div class="menu">
<ul>
    <li class="page_item page-item-2"><a href="http://lukas-macbook-2.local/wordpress/?page_id=2">Sample Page</a></li>
</ul>
```

Problem is that in output `<ul>` doesn't have data-role assigned as it should have.

Anyone have an idea why this function doesn't get the parameter right?

Comment: What's your problem? What isn't showing?

Comment: ul has to have class in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this code:

```
<ul class="menu">
<?php wp_nav_menu( array(

    'menu'           =>     'mobile-menu',
    'theme_location' =>     'main-navigation',
    'container'       => false,
    'items_wrap'      => '%3$s'  ) ); ?>

</ul>
```

Comment: This doesn't help at all. Output still has container div and ul list. It seems like the function doesn't care what parameters it has.

Comment: Could you call this `get_registered_nav_menus()` function a do a `var_dump` of the result?

Comment: `array(1) {
  ["main-navigation"]=>
  string(15) "Navigation Menu"
}`

Comment: Ok, the location exists. But have you created the menu from the admin panel?

Comment: That was it! I forgot to create the menu itself. Thank you!